# Finitely generated torsion free module over $A$ is locally free

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

> Assume that $A$ is an integral domain whose local rings $A_p$ are principal ideal domains. Show that any finitely generated torsion-free module over $A$ is locally free.

I know that finitely generated torsion-free modules over a PID are free. How to apply this here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is a torsion-free $A$-module, then $M_p$ is a torsion-free $A_p$-module.

Comment: is it something like this ?
Suppose $m/s \in M_p$. If its torsion then there is $a/s$ such that $a/s \cdot m/s = 0 $ so there is $x \in A$ such that $x \cdot am = 0$ so M is not torsion free

Comment: @Itachi Almost.

Comment: So because of this, I can localize and $M_p$ would still be finitely generated and torsion free. So $M_p$ is torsion free, fin.gen over PID $A_p$  thus $M_p$ free ?

Comment: @Itachi Exactly.